# Is there a way to play Orcs and Elves on PC or Android?

Tags: orcs-and-elves

I played Orc's and Elves 7 Years ago on Nintendo DS and upon coming across it again recently, I want to play it again.

I want to know if there's any way to play it on PC (Win 7 , 64 bit) or on an Android mobile Sony Xperia Y5 (not mine). I've tried downloading .jar files on the Xperia but I am unsure how to run them (and/or if its safe to do so).

Comment: Running jar files is a generic computing task, and has nothing to do with gaming.

Comment: Yes so they would all be fake i'd say. It was a java game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orcs_%26_Elves) *Orcs and Elves* was originally released on Nintendo DS and 'Mobile Phone', the latter of which is likely the version from which these `.jar`. files you're talking about are from.

The 'Mobile Phone' version predates a lot of today's Smartphones, and thus isn't an indicator that it will run natively on your mobile phone today. That old `.jar` file is likely built for a specific version of the Java ME system, trying to find that exact version and then trying to get that working on a PC or Android device will be a difficult task.

So despite the 'Mobile Phone' version existing, it may just be simpler to run the Nintendo DS version of the game. You can either:

- Pick up a (fairly cheap) DS from second-hand electronics, gaming or thrift stores
- Buy a Nintendo 3DS (which runs DS games)
- Run the game through an emulator. for example, [**nds4droid**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opendoorstudios.ds4droid&hl=en) on Anrdoid or [**DeSmuME**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/desmume/) on PC.

The reason this will be simpler is that as far as the game is concerned it's running on the 'same' hardware as a Nintendo DS (even if under the hood it's emulated).